# Is it possible to define an is-a relation ship in laravel using eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to define the relationships of my database in my models but I can't find the way of defining an is-a relationship. I have a table named users and every user might be admin or main user. How should I define this kind of relationship?

Comment: A user may have one or many roles (admin or main user). So in your case, this is called a _one-to-many_ relationship.

Comment: You can just use this plugin if you don't want to DIY
`spatie/laravel-permission`.

And your approach is incorrect. You would save All Permissions in one table & Users in Another Table. To establish that a given user is Admin.
You would define User belongs to Admin (Admin would be a single row on permission table).

Comment: I highly recommend doing this on your own to get a feel for it google something like how to implement roles and permissions in laravel and there are a bunch of how toos.  It'll help you see how things work by building it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I quite understood your question, the best way of doing that is creating the class `MainUser` and the class `Admin`. Both classes must extend from the standard `User` class.

Then, you create the specific methods for each class, like `isAdmin()` and `isMainUser()`.